# Issue with react-native-scrollable-tab-view and their props :( (react native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Library: [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong :/ I'd like to change the tabBarBackgroundColor:

```
export default class MainNavigation extends Component{
  render() {
    return (<ScrollableTabView
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
      initialPage={1}
      renderTabBar={() => <FacebookTabBar />}
      tabBarPosition="bottom"
      locked={true}
      tabBarBackgroundColor = "#FF0000" // <------
      tabBarActiveTextColor = "#FF0000" // <------
      >
      <ScrollView tabLabel="list-ul" style={styles.tabView}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Übersicht</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      ...
```

But it's ignoring it and is doing nothing >.<

*tabBarPosition="bottom"* and *locked={true}* are working just fine.

Any hints? Would really appreciate it :)

Greetings,
Stefanie ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set `tabBarBackgroundColor` and other tabBar styles when you are using a custom `renderTabBar`

This styles will work if you remove the `renderTabBar`function.

You will need to adapt the colors in your `<FacebookTabBar />` component